# junit custom runner implementation

Tags: java, junit, junit-runner

I am trying to customize a runner for junit. I am using the Extended runner given here:

http://codehowtos.blogspot.com/2011/04/run-junit-test-repeatedly.html

adding my own created Filter Runner's code, which extends Runner, to the ExtendedRunner which i got from the above link. When i try to run the test it gives me the below error.

```
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:157)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:102)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:336)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:74)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:56)
    at com.util.ExtendedRunner.<init>(ExtendedRunner.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

any help to resolve the same??

Comment: Are you using different ClassLoaders? If you are, then the `@Test.class` loaded when setting up the TestRunner may not be equal to the one detected when looking for annotated methods.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, your `ExtendedRunner` extends `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner` that extends the `ParentRunner`. When looking at the code of this last class, the only thing done in the constructor is to "register" the class you passed to this runner and its information.

So most likely, the class does not have any methods tagged as tests. If you are using JUnit 4, don't forget the `@Test` annotation before all test methods.